# character movement python (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to call moveleft method but there is no movement. i pass the distance of the character and this should be updated but its not. Any ideas?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()


width,height=(842,595)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("game!")
speedX=3
movingX =0
clock= pygame.time.Clock()



man = pygame.image.load("man.png")
target= pygame.image.load("target.png")




x = 100
y = height-300




def name(name=""):
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 15)
    label = myfont.render(name, 1, (255,255,0))
    result=window.blit(label, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    return name

def moveleft(distanceX):
    movingX =0
    speedX =0
    x=0
    while True:

        pygame.display.update()
        ticks=clock.tick(25)
        time_passedSeconds=ticks/1000.0

        distanceX = time_passeSeconds*speedX
        movingX+=distanceX
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==K_LEFT:
                    x+=distanceX



        window.blit(man, (x,y))
    return movingX




name("werodo!")
moveleft(5)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You draw the character at `(x, y)`. The only time you change `x` is here:

```
            elif event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==K_LEFT:
                    x+=distanceX
```

What is `distanceX`? It changes every iteration of the loop:

```
        distanceX = time_passeSeconds*speedX
```

Yet you only assign `speedX` once at the start of the function:

```
    speedX = 0
```

So, you're always moving by `0`. Change `speedX` to `50` and see what happens.

Comment: @Pro-grammer: it worked for me. Actually it made him move right, but something happened.  had to change `time_passeSeconds` to `time_passedSeconds` to get it to work though.. how are you running this code?

Comment: i want the distance the character moves reflect on the function call:
moveleft(3) so if the speed is 50 it should go at that speed

Comment: @Pro-grammer: at what speed? 3 pixels/second? 50 pixels/second? Right now it only moves when you press the left arrow key...

Comment: i want the move method to deplict movement based on speed

Comment: @Pro-grammer: ok, so why are you only changing the man's `x` coordinate on the `elif event.type==KEYDOWN`?

Comment: no idea:( i should really be changing the speed right. Darn, coding = 14hours :/

Comment: @Pro-grammer: hmm your code is pretty confused, it doesn't make a lot of sense.. you don't seem to get some basics of pygame. maybe try checking [this program](http://www.pygame.org/project-Sprite+Movement+Towards+a+Target-1538-.html) out and studying it to learn how it works

Comment: To move 50 pixels/sec while key is **held down**, use [get_keystate()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) . Using the keydown event will only fire **once per press**

Comment: `key.get_pressed()` is not the best way to do this.  If in the future you want to know the order in which buttons were pressed between two calls to `key.get_pressed()`, you will be out of luck.  It is better to monitor the events, and keep a boolean mapping of the keys you are interested in.  Also, quick key presses may go entirely unnoticed using `key.get_pressed()`.  You will only see the keys which were pressed at the time of the function call.